# AG-Grid Side Bar click functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

So I have a side bar built using ag-grid and was wondering if it was possible to click on a side bar option without having the tool panel open and have a pop up component instead?

```
const gridOptions = {
    sideBar: {
        toolPanels: [
            {
                id: 'columns',
                labelDefault: 'Columns',
                labelKey: 'columns',
                iconKey: 'columns',
                toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
                minWidth: 225,
                maxWidth: 225,
                width: 225
            },
            {
                id: 'filters',
                labelDefault: 'Filters',
                labelKey: 'filters',
                iconKey: 'filter',
                toolPanel: 'agFiltersToolPanel',
                minWidth: 180,
                maxWidth: 400,
                width: 250
            },
            {
                id: 'myComponent',
                labelDefault: 'MyComponent',
                labelKey: 'myComponent',
                iconKey: 'myComponent',
                toolPanel: () => {<MyComponent/>},
                minWidth: 180,
                maxWidth: 400,
                width: 250
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

For example, in the above code, I pass a component (e.g. `<MyComponent/>`) in place of the tool panel, but it doesn't actually open that component when I click on it since it renders on the sideBar loading up.

Can I pass some onClick function into that particular sideBar option to allow me to click on it and open the component?

Comment: you just want to add your component to the side bar as tab or want to totally replace the side bar?

Comment: I want to totally replace the side bar just for that option